# Cannot login to OS X 10.9 because password field disappears after clicking username

Tags: macos, imac

I didn't add or do anything to computer except reboot. When the login screen appeared with my user account I clicked it as usual and the password box briefly appears and then disappears stopping me from logging in. How can I fix this? I do have a guest account with limited capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

That is odd and I have not seen it before, the only thing I can think of is to boot in Safe Mode in the hopes that there is something running on your Mac that is causing that or interfering with login.

Boot your Mac holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> untill the apple logo pops up then release the key and let it boot. It will likely take longer to boot and eventually you will see "Safe Mode" on the boot/login screen. Try it then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I went to the Apple store today and it turned out to be my keyboard.  I bought a new keyboard and all is good now.